# Why python automatically returns character counts when write file

Tags: python

I recently noticed that when I have the following code:

```
File = "/dir/to/file"
Content = "abcdefg"

with open(File,"a") as f:
    f.write(Content)
```

I got "7" as an output and it is the count of characters in the variable "Content". I do not recall seeing this (I used ipython notebook before, but this time I did it in the python environment in shell) and wonder if I did something wrong. My python version: Python 3.3.3. Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is normal behaviour

Comment: [`f.write(string)` writes the contents of `string` to the file, returning the number of characters written.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Comment: @PatrickHaugh what you mean by normal behaviour!? Coz, the string is stored into a variable `Content` and that is being written to the file if I did get the question right. Can you please be more elaborate.

Comment: This is normal and documented behavior. AFAIK, `f.write` has always worked this way, and works similar to C functions in that sense (e.g. `fprintf`)

Comment: Thank you people for your helpful comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always this behaviour is normal for most `.write()` implementations, see also [I/O Base Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#i-o-base-classes).

For example [`io.RawIOBase.write`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase.write)

> Write the given bytes-like object, b, to the underlying raw stream, and return the number of bytes written.

or [`io.TextIOBase.write`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.write)

> Write the string s to the stream and return the number of characters written.

Which `IO`-class is used depends on (the OS and) the parameters given to `open`. But as far as I can see all of them return some sort of "characters" or "bytes" written count.

Comment: Thank you so much @MSeifert . I've been using ipython notebook and recently switched to directly do it in shell command. In ipython notebook I've never seen such behavior lol.